# The listener does not work! Django-signals

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class MyModel(models.Model):
   int = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)

def added (sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print 'Added'  


post_save.connect(added,MyModel)
```

When I do:

```
MyModel.objects.create(int=12345).save()
```

nothing happened

Am i lose something?

After Edit:

Not working.

Comment: Just tested this with Django 1.2. Worked perfectly for me. If you did not already, can you fire up the Django shell `./manage.py shell` and try this again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're connecting `added()` to `MyModel` instead of `BitRate`, so it's not surprising that `added()` is not fired when a bitrate is saved...

Comment: Yeh! It just writing mistake. In real I use model Bitrate

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting `post_save` to `MyModel`, but you're creating and saving `Bitrate`.  Is that a typo?